# closest lattice point type question

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics

I can't seem to find a solution to this problem. Let's set Z^2 to be the integer lattice in R^2. Given a rational ray (meaning a vector with rational slope), is there a fast method to compute the closest lattice point to this vector in terms of orthogonal distance? Can this method be generalized to a hyperplane in R^n?

Answer (score 2):

Your question does not seem well defined. How do you define the distance to a vector ?
If you're asking for the closest distance from the lattice to the line whose direction is a rational vector (as suggested by your generalization) then the answer is zero, thanks to the rationality: your direction is D = (n1/d1, n2/d2). Then, the point (d2*n1, d1*n2) is on the line.

For the smallest *non-zero* distance :

We can assume that d1=d2=d : D = (n1/d, n2/d) (which you can get by setting e.g. d = d1*d2). Now, the possible distances from the unit-grid lattice to the line are of the form (Z*n1 + Z*n2)/d = (Z*gcd(n1,n2))/d where Z is the set of integers. (This is a consequence of Bézout theorem). So the minimal non zero distance is gcd(n1,n2)/d where gcd(.,.) gives the greatest common divisor of two integers.

Comment: Distance is Euclidean distance. In this case, I would want to minimize  distance in the normal direction. Of course, I'm asking about points _off_ the line!

Comment: I might be wrong, but if there is a point on the line, then whatever distance you take, it will be zero at that point, be it euclidian distance (which is the same as the distance in the normal direction for a line), or l1 distance, or whatever. Probably I did not understand your question.